# Costum Theme template directoy url problem

Tags: themes, errors

recently i've made a costum wordpress theme , i already made few before but this time i'm really confused about issue:

issue is ; in costum theme i'm using this :

get_template_directory_uri() to get the current theme 's url for getting his js files and css files work , but some how at the palce of my current theme name it is replacing with twenty twelve theme name , my costum theme is not an child of twenty twelve .

style.css header code :

```
/*
Theme Name: Nicole 's New Theme.
Theme URI: http//:www.itmatic.io/.
Description: This Theme is created by itmatic , please do not edit anything , just make    an child theme and do the changes.
Version: 1.0
Author: Itmatic
Author URI: http//:www.itmatic.io/.
*/
@import url("assets/css/reset.css");
@import url("assets/css/style.css");
```

Comment: Can you post the [stylesheet header](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Theme_Stylesheet) of your theme?

Comment: @cybmeta  i have posted the header code please check :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri

Using this has helped me with this type of issue in the past.

Comment: Awsome with wokred :D ,,, but can you tell me why there is still twentytwelve navigation.js loaded in my costum theme? as i don't even inlueded it? :(

Comment: is your theme built by using twentytwelve as its foundation?

Comment: @joseph-neathwak  once i connected it to twenty twelve but after 5 min i removed the template: twentytwelve , because i do have all my own costum functions.

Comment: My first thought is to do a hard refresh of the page. If it still exists, then do a search through your code to see where `navigation.js` is being used. It is likely in the `header.php` or `functions.php`. I can see that your style header shows this is NOT a child theme, so my next thought is that you built this theme by first copying twentytwelve and then making any changes you wanted to it. There is nothing wrong with that at all, but it can cause this type of problem by leaving around bits of code that you aren't using.

Comment: Thanks joseph for the great help :), will do as you said (Y)